# Regex not matching when more characters are added

Tags: javascript, regex

String 1:
`STARTRequestId:b4114e7d-a3e1-42c9-8104-87c3444757f8Version:$LATESTENDRequestId:b4114e7d-a3e1-42c9-8104-87c3444757f8REPORTRequestId:b4114e7d-a3e1-42c9-8104-87c3444757f8Duration:301.78msBilledDuration:400msMemorySize:256MBMaxMemoryUsed:85MBInitDuration:258.30ms`

String 2: 
`STARTRequestId:462e68f9-346f-48c0-8592-762f78e84010Version:$LATESTENDRequestId:462e68f9-346f-48c0-8592-762f78e84010REPORTRequestId:462e68f9-346f-48c0-8592-762f78e84010Duration:108.69msBilledDuration:200msMemorySize:128MBMaxMemoryUsed:85MB`

Between String 1 & String 2, there is the addition of `InitDuration:258.30ms`

I'm trying to regex the above output, currently, I have:

`/Duration:(?<actualTime>(?!.*\..*\.)[.\d]+)msBilledDuration:(?<billedTime>(?!.*\..*\.)[.\d]+)msMemorySize:(?<memorySize>(?!.*\..*\.)[.\d]+)MB/`

The above matches within String 2, but on String 1... However when `InitDuration:258.30ms` is added (String 1) the regex fails and finds no results are found. I do NOT need the additional match, my goal is to maintain `actualTime`, `billedTime`, and `memorySize` regardless if the rest exists.

Comment: I think tt fails due to the lookahead `(?!.*\..*\.)` and the dot in this value `258.30ms` Why do you need the lookahead? Would this be ok? https://regex101.com/r/wfHKUN/1

Comment: https://regexr.com/4n6eu

Comment: Be aware that named capture groups are not supported in all browsers, for example Firefox doesn't.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Good catch, I wouldn't need a lookahead here and missed that.

Comment: @Toto Noted, thanks! This is node/backend here, but good to know.

Comment: Perhaps use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead of `[.\d]` to prevent matching dots only https://regex101.com/r/mIgqGy/1

Comment: So, why do you have `(?!.*\..*\.)`? `Duration:(\d[.\d]*)msBilledDuration:(\d[.\d]*)msMemorySize:(\d[.\d]*)MB` [will do](https://regex101.com/r/Mqw1PD/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not match the first string due to the negative lookahead `(?!.*\..*\.)`

The negative lookahead asserts what is on the right does not contain 2 dots which will fail for the first string because there are `301.78` and `258.30ms`.

It will match for the second string because there is only a single value `108.69` that contains a dot.

If you only want to maintain actualTime, billedTime and memorySize you could omit the lookahead. To prevent matching a dot only using `[.\d]+` you could match digits with an optional decimal part `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

The pattern might look like

```
Duration:(?<actualTime>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)msBilledDuration:(?<billedTime>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)msMemorySize:(?<memorySize>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)MB
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mIgqGy/1/)